# With Python openpyxl how do you change the font size in a chart legend?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

With Python openpyxl how do you change the font size in a chart legend.

```
#Create Chart
chart1 = BarChart()
chart1.type = "col"
chart1.style = 10
chart1.title = "Rolling 4 weeeeks"
chart1.legend.position = 'b'
chart1.legend.font = FONT(name = 'Calibri', size = 9)
```

and my chart legend text is still size 10

thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

There is no `.font` attribute for `Legend()`.

The [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.chart.legend.html#openpyxl.chart.legend.Legend.txPr)  for `Legend()` states:

> txPr (alias: textProperties)
>
> ```
> Values must be of type <class ‘openpyxl.chart.text.RichText’>
> ```

You need to modify the legend like this:

```
from openpyxl.chart.text import RichText
from openpyxl.drawing.text import Paragraph, ParagraphProperties, CharacterProperties, Font


font = Font(typeface='Verdana')
size = 2000 # 20 point size
cp = CharacterProperties(latin=font, sz=size, b=True) # Try bold text
pp = ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp)
rtp = RichText(p=[Paragraph(pPr=pp, endParaRPr=cp)])

ch1.legend.textProperties = rtp
```

(Inspired by [Formatting chart data labels in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47550555/formatting-chart-data-labels-in-openpyxl))