# Format chart data labels as percentage to 1dp with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to use Python and openpyxl to go through a bunch of workbooks and collect data, then write the data to a report. This includes a pie chart, which I want to display the data labels as percentages to 1dp. I couldn't seem to find a way to do so. It can be done easily enough natively in Excel by going Format Data Labels -> Number -> Category(Percentage) -> Decimal places. But I can't seem to find a way to do it using openpyxl. Any suggestions? I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47550555/formatting-chart-data-labels-in-openpyxl), but it didn't answer my question.

Example code:

```
import openpyxl as op
from openpyxl.chart import(
    PieChart,
    Reference
)
from openpyxl.chart.label import DataLabelList

# Creating excel sheet
wb = op.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# Data, writing to excel sheet
data = [
    ['Pie', 'Sold'],
    ['Apple', 24],
    ['Pumpkin', 13],
    ['Berry', 17]
]
for row in data:
    ws.append(row)

# Creating pie chart
pie = PieChart()
labels = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=4)
data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_row=4)
pie.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
pie.set_categories(labels)
pie.title = 'Pies sold'

# Showing data labels as percentage
pie.dataLabels = DataLabelList()
pie.dataLabels.showPercent = True

# Adding chart
ws.add_chart(pie, 'D1')

# Saving
save_location = r"C:\Users\jw\Desktop\\"
wb.save(save_location + "Test.xlsx")
```

Comment: This is just a copy from the openpyxl documentation and contains no attempt to format the values.

Comment: @CharlieClark I know, wasn't making any claims otherwise. Was asking for suggestions as to how to format it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround.

Before writing the data to excel, it needs to be reformatted as a decimal portion of the total (0.67, 0.02 etc.). Then write to excel, change the format as desired:
`ws.cell(row=row, column=column).number_format = '0.0%'`
Create the chart as per usual, but use `pie.dataLabels.showVal = True` instead of `pie.dataLabels.showPercent = True`
The pie chart will now display the data labels to 1dp. Other formats also work if you're after something unconventional. Hope this helps someone